# Show a dialog fragment from another dialog fragment

Tags: android, callback, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment called DialogFragmentOne inside that i am displaying a recyclerView. On the item click of that recyclerView call an another webservice on post execute  of that service i am trying to show another dialogeFragment which also contains recyclerview. but on calling second dialog ishows some error

call for second dialogeFragment form service is

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        dialogeInterface.getModifierList(modifierList,hasModifier);
    }
```

and inside FirstDialogeFragment

```
@Override
    public void getModifierList(ArrayList<String> modifierList, boolean hasModifier) {

        if (hasModifier) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        ModifierListDIalogeFragment dialog = new ModifierListDIalogeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("modifierList", modifierList);
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);
        dialog.show(manager.beginTransaction(), "dialog");

        }
    }
```

and i got an error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
                      at package.xxx.com.pos_system.fragments.ItemListDialogeFragment.getModifierList(ItemListDialogeFragment.java:140)
```

Comment: did u try with `getChildFragmentManager()` ? it is used to display fragment inside another fragment.

Comment: yes at first time i used that

Comment: at that time error is IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Answer (score 0):

The reason is context is null .Use Activity context

```
if (hasModifier) {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager() 
    ModifierListDIalogeFragment dialog = new ModifierListDIalogeFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("modifierList", modifierList);
    dialog.setArguments(bundle);
    dialog.show(manager.beginTransaction(), "dialog");

    }
```

Comment: Already try this getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() again crashes with same log.

Comment: can you post that logcat

Comment: post the line ItemListDialogeFragment.java:140

Comment: that line is inside getModifierList() -140) dialog.setArguments